# Is nginx timeout or rails timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I deployed rails app with nginx and passenger,there is a long running rails action, something like this:

```
 def handler
  sleep 100
  respond_to do |format|
     format.json { render :json=>{:success=>true}}
  end
end
```

However, the nginx error log print this message:

```
Couldn't forward the HTTP response back to the HTTP client: It seems the user clicked on the 'Stop' button in his browser.
```

Obviously,this error don't called by click stop button. Maybe nginx timeout or rails time out or passenger timeout, how to solve this problem, is it possible be solved by configure file. Is there any help

Comment: Rails doesn't have a request timeout. I think it's enginx in your case: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_connect_timeout or http://www.nginxtips.com/504-gateway-time-out-using-nginx/

Comment: It is because you use passenger built-in Nginx module, start using standalone process via upstream configuration and problem should be fixed.

Comment: thx，i found the reason，i use extjs Ajax request front which default timeout is 30sec.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx isn't getting a response from Passenger in time.

You can increase the timeout via nginx config via the max_execution_time.

The standard way to handle this would be to kick the sleep 100 to a background job (DJ, Resque et, I personally prefer resque as my go to but DJ is easy to setup and there are an almost infinite number of pre-built offers available).

Then you would return a 202 which means "accepted" and is used to indicate that the processing of the request is not complete but the server did receive the request.

Comment: thx，i found the reason，i use extjs Ajax request front which default timeout is 30sec.